# Smallest number recorded in a cell

Tags: google-sheets, google-finance

A value in a cell that changes automatically (using Google Finance), I want to record the lowest value in another cell.

Comment: Both Excel and Google Sheets have functions like MIN and MAX to find the smallest and highest number in a range.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot create a permanent snapshot of a cell value with a spreadsheet formula, so you will have to use a script.

See the [appendValuesToArchiveSheet](https://support.google.com/docs/thread/27095918?msgid=27163801) script for one possible solution. You can use it to copy the value in the cell in another sheet in a log file of sorts on an hourly or daily basis and then apply `min()` function to get the lowest value.